# Adding Buttons in DOS

Tags: c++, button, click, dos

How can I add a button in a c++ dos evironment? One where when you click it, it creates a response from the game.  (If there is a library and an A file, I can add those)

Comment: Much to vague... I think your question should be something like, "which library is suitable for creating a graphical button you can click in a game for DOS" or so.

Comment: By DOS environment do you mean a console app in Windows? You should be able to link whatever libs you want but if you want GUI elements you should make a GUI application (windows API, MFC, .NET, QT, wxWidgets, whatever)

Comment: Also, do you really want to code for DOS?  And in that case, which computer do you run DOS on? Is it 16-bit = 8088, 8086 or 80286? If 80386 or higher, you can run more advanced programs, like DOS extenders.

Comment: Don't be discouraged that your question was closed, it happens to a lot of StackOverflow beginners ALL the time.  Just keep asking questions, you will learn from the comments how to improve your questions. Good luck with your game programming! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... in which case I would suggest [Allegro](http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/allegro/readme.html) 4.2 for DOS. But that only works in 80386 and higher CPUs, not 16-bit computers.

Comment: Ok let me see if that library is here

Comment: +1 allegro is quite nice for gamedev in general.

Comment: +1 for recommending Allegro. It is excellent for such purposes. (Used in linux, not in DOS)

Answer (score 1):

Would this help ?

http://www.stanq.com/dosbuttons.html
Or we have [Allegro](http://www.talula.demon.co.uk/allegro/wip.html)
I would recommend Allegro

You can have a look of a [review of allegro](http://phoxis.org/2009/02/13/allegro-422/) here on my blog. And get the [UI Button and other widget manual here](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/stabledocs/en/alleg035.html)

To learn allegro you can read: [Game Programming All In One by Jonathan S. Harbour.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1598632892) . It is a good one for beginners.

Comment: That would  be perfect but does it contain how to write the code?

Comment: Ok but does it contain libraries that would let me create simple buttons

Comment: yes it does: you can read a review on allegro here: [on my blog](http://phoxis.org/2009/02/13/allegro-422/) and here is the [UI manual](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/stabledocs/en/alleg035.html)

Comment: I just downloaded the allegro file but I don't know how to create buttons

Comment: read the manual its very good. probably go to the allegro forum, and see the samples in the downloaded source file. they have excellent examples there.

Comment: Ok let me try that. Buttons really aren't essential to my game, but it would add a lot.

Comment: check the book i have updated in the answer.

Comment: Ok I will. That will help a lot

Comment: Phoxis, persistent in helping, +1. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Command line is pretty much text only. If you want to use the mouse, or any kind of non-text GUI you will need a library and the library you use depends entirely on what you want to do.

Comment: Ok, Do you know any library that can support that?

Comment: Basically, don't do this. If you want to make an event driven Windows GUI application, use Win32. If you want a text-only command line app, use the command line. They do not mix.

Comment: Ok. But do I have to learn new code to code a Win32

Comment: Well, you will have to learn some of the Windows APIs, but it can all be done with C/C++.

Comment: Ok Thats good.    I'll look at that

Answer (score 0):

You should use a UI library if you want to create UI type things.  MFC, QT or Win32 API are one's I know about for windows.  In the Console, I think it would be very hard to create buttons.

Comment: Ok. But do I have to change the source code for a Win32 App

Comment: You have to create a Win32 project in VS, then you can use Win32.  Or just create a blank project and code it all yourself, but if you're new I don't advice that

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the coordinates of the mouse click and determine if they are within the with button.  If they are within the button, you should change the button's color to indicate a press, then perform some action (or execute through a function pointer).

This is how most GUI frameworks handle buttons.

(You may want to move away from DOS and use a Graphics Framework for Windows.)